Java Linear Interpolation
Good day all.
Given an ArrayList having float values [254.0f, 266.0f,......]
What is the best way to linearly interpolate values, between 254.0 and 266.0, assuming I know that I want to split this interval into (for example) 5 equal sub-intervals.
i.e (266 - 254 = 12)/5 = 2.4  per step.
So start at 254 and simply loop to add 1 x 2.4 , 2 x 2.4 etc until we reach 266.
This should work but is there an easier way to linearly interpolate ? Im trying to avoid the loop. The loop is simple but for some reason, unknown to me, my Android Studio is refusing to execute the loop. No idea why?
Thanks
Paul
